# How to check the List<SqlRow> is empty

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I am using a `Ebean` query

```
String sql = " some sql query";

List<SqlRow> row = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql).findList(); //Ebean return the row list 

if ((row == null) && row.isEmpty()){ //if row is there is no value then allocate 700    
  avgSteps=700;         
}
else {
  for(SqlRow sqlrow : row) {        
     avgSteps = sqlrow.getLong("step");
  }
}
```

if the user doesn't have a entry in my `DB` then it should return a null and the value allocated to `avgSteps = 700` but it's doesn't allocate the value ,and `NullPoinertException` occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
String sql = " some sql query";

List<SqlRow> row = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql).findList(); //Ebean return the row list 

if ((row.size() == 0)){ //if row is there is no value then allocate 700    
  avgSteps=700;         
}
else {
  for(SqlRow sqlrow : row) {        
     avgSteps = sqlrow.getLong("step");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `if` condition as follows:

```
if ((row == null) || row.isEmpty())
```

You want to check if the row is *either* null or empty, not *both* null and empty.

Comment: Thank for your answer I have tried or condition also... but row.isEmpty() is not working accordingly. If there are no element then it should return true. but it doesn't.